# FIM Synchronization Server doesn't start - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Having problems with FIM Sychronization Service, its fails to start with following message in Application logs

---

The server encountered an unexpected error and stopped.

```
 "BAIL: MMS(9948): sql.cpp(8490): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported values.)
BAIL: MMS(9948): sql.cpp(8533): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported values.)
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(260): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported values.)
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported values.)
BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported values.)
ERR: MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2145184972. This is retry number 0.
BAIL: MMS(9948): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 1.
BAIL: MMS(9948): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 2.
BAIL: MMS(9948): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 
ERR: MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 3.
BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1002): 0x80131022
```

---

We are running on Dec 12 CU patch.
Checked the registry keys at following location, looks all the keys have correct values
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FIMSynchronizationService\Parameters

The service is running under farm administrator account, it is added in the local administrators as well (for the time being, just to provision UPS).

Ran Process Monitor for any Access Violations but it came neat.

Searched all around, nothing helped, please help if anybody has faced such issue before?

Not sure why the service doesn't log detailed information in some log file.

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

﻿

Installed Client Configuration Utility for SQL Server for checking the network protocol as somebody had mentioned in a forum (both TCP, namedpipe were enabled). This required a reboot.

Again went in Central Administration, tried running Synchronization Service, failed checked the event logs and found following message

The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob (ID 23f8c125-f4f5-45a4-8180-576478fdeffd) threw an exception. More information is included below.
An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. 
The object ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance was updated by DOMAIN\ADMIN_Farm, in the OWSTIMER (2576) process, on machine APPSERVER001.blah.com.
View the tracing log for more information about the conflict.Checked the ULS Viewer found following

Found multiple errors from owtimer.exe but this one was a good indication

ConcurrencyException: Old Version : 49462 New Version : 49502and this one

ProfileSynchronizationService: Provisioning TImer Job encountered an exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance was updated by DOMAIN\ADMIN_Farm, in the OWSTIMER (2576) process, on machine APPSERVER001.blah.com.  View the tracing log for more information about the conflict.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.StoreObject(SPPersistedObject obj, Boolean storeClassIfNecessary, Boolean ensure)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.PutObject(SPPersistedObject persistedObject, Boolean ensure)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance profileSyncInstance)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob.Execute(SPJobState state)We had applied the CU recently and ran the configuration wizard as well, but seemed somehow all the components were not updated.

Ran the SharePoint Configuration Wizard till the time it brings the central admin, chose the manual option and exited the screen.

Went to ths services page, tried starting the service again and it worked this time.